# How to convert the following decimal? to String("F2")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have Decimal? Amount

In my model I have a value as @item.Sales, which I`m trying to write as @item.Sales.ToString("F2").

I`m having the message error Error  1   No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

How can I achieve the above

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If it's a nullable decimal, you need to get the non-nullable value first:

```
@item.Sales.Value.ToString("F2")
```

Of course, that will throw an exception if `@item.Sales` is actually a null value, so you'd need to check for that first.

Comment: Yep, just add "if (@item.Sales.HasValue) { ...do the conversion... }"

Comment: I`m not having the HasValue method in my View. The error message is Error 1 'decimal' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue' and no extension method 'HasValue' accepting a first argument of type 'decimal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user281180: In that case your value *isn't* of type `decimal?` in the first place - why did you include the question mark in the middle of your title? But then calling `ToString("F2")` should be fine...

Comment: @jon: value is of type decimal?. The code @item.Sales.ToString("F2") works well if it`s of type decimal and not decimal?

Comment: @user281180: If the value is really of type `decimal?` then you should be able to use `HasValue`. The compiler error strongly suggests that the type *is* just `decimal` rather than `decimal?`. Whichever, *either* `@item.Sales.HasValue` *or* `@item.Sales.ToString("F2")` should work. You weren't trying `@item.Sales.Value.HasValue` were you?

Comment: @Jon, I just can`t get th .HasValue...Am I missing any reference?

Comment: @user281180: No, but it's not clear *exactly* what you're trying. Does `@item.Sales.Value.ToString("F2")` work?

Comment: I can hardly access the .Value, it gives me error when I write @item.sales.Value

Comment: @user281180: Well is it `@item.Sales` or `@item.sales`? C# is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

You could create an Extension method so the main code is simpler

```
  public static class DecimalExtensions
  {
    public static string ToString(this decimal? data, string formatString, string nullResult = "0.00")
    {
      return data.HasValue ? data.Value.ToString(formatString) : nullResult;
    }
  }
```

And you can call it like this:

```
  decimal? value = 2.1234m;
  Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("F2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( item.Sales.HasValue )
{
    item.Sales.Value.ToString(....)
}
else
{
 //exception handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the unary ? operator to run .ToString() only when there's an object

```
@item.Sales?.ToString("F2")
```

Or use the double ?? operator thus makes it non-nullable:

```
@((item.Sales??0).ToString("F2"))
```

This is better than `@item.Sales.Value.Tostring("F2")` because if you don't check for null value before using `.ToString("F2")` the code will break at runtime.

Comment: Or if you want to leave null values blank; `@item.Sales?.ToString("F2")`

Comment: Thanks @JeremyLakeman, I will update my answer with your suggestion as it uses less code to achieve a similar effect.